# How to prevent multiline edittext from pushing text upwards?

Tags: java, android

I have a Recycler List that stores multiline EditTexts in recyclerview  item layout files like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56sIp.png)

Whenever a user types multiple lines in the edittext, however, the edittext pushes the previous lines of text in the same edittext upwards so that you can't see them anymore. I was wondering if there was a way around this or if I could expand the height of my edittext/recyclerview item layout file containing my edit text to accomadate for the added lines.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You could set the default lines show in preview with `android:lines="5"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind I solved it. I had to make the editText's height 'wrap content' so that the height of the layout item file increased along with the new lines of text.